# Issues in EMR add step to submit a spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, emr, spark-submit

I tried to submit a spark job with 2 dependent jar packages A.jar and B.jar on EMR with below command

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-1WM5F79YY6EIN --steps Type=Spark,Name="test", \
Args=[--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,myClassName,--jars, \
"s3://myBucketName/project.jar,s3://myBucketName/A.jar,s3://myBucketName/B.jar", \
s3://myBucketName/project.jar,param1,value1,param2,value2] --region us-west-2
```

Two issues here:

1. only the first two jar package could be accepted in --jars parameter. in above command, ClassNotFound exception is thrown for class in B.jar. If I submitted with --jars,"s3://myBucketName/project.jar,s3://myBucketName/B.jar,s3://myBucketName/A.jar". ClassNotFound exception is thrown for class in A.jar
2. I have to put project.jar as the first jar in --jars parameter, thought I need to provide it again as app jar later in the command. Otherwise, main class could not be found.

Not quite familiar with EMR so any help on my questions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your problem, but according to the [release guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html), you should avoid spaces in the arguments list:

> When you use the AWS CLI, the items in your Args list should be comma
> separated with no whitespace between list elements. For example,
> Args=[example-command,example-option,"example option value"] instead
> of Args=[example-command, example-option, "example option value"].

It looks like there are spaces in your example.